# Fetch String of map in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have dynamodb table structure as follows:

{
  "id": "1",
  "skills": {
    "skill1": "html",
    "skill2": "css"
  }
}

I have task to filter by skills value, In order to complete my task wrote java logic as follows:

```
 AmazonDynamoDB client = dynamoDBService.getClient();

      DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client); 
      Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("dummy");
      Map<String, String> attributeNames = new HashMap<String, String >();
      attributeNames.put("#columnValue", "skills.skill1");
      Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
      attributeValues.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS("html"));

      ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withProjectionExpression("skills.skill1")
              .withFilterExpression("#columnValue = :val1 ").withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#columnValue",  "skills.skill1")) 
                 .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":val1", "html"));

      ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = table.scan(scanSpec);  
         Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator(); 

         while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Item item = iter.next(); 
            System.out.println("--------"+item.toString()); 
         }
```

The mentioned code does not help me out. Any solution ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what you want do to in detail.

Comment: As i mentioned in query,i would like fetch single row by skills, html or css.. etc.

for example: select * from table_name where skills=html, css,...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ProjectionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) to retrieve only specific attributes or elements, rather than an entire item. A ProjectionExpression can specify top-level or nested attributes, using document paths.

for example from AWS:

```
GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("Id", 206)
    .withProjectionExpression("Id, Title, RelatedItems[0], Reviews.FiveStar")
    .withConsistentRead(true);

Item item = table.getItem(spec);

System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
```

Comment: As metioned snippet code, I have only skill value to filter.how to fetch by GettemSpec?? or any other example in Java???

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to this problem is:

1. First fetch all the records from the table.
2. Then iterate over the list of that object.
3. Extract the skills from each object.
4. Wrote your logic to do filtering.
5. Repeat the loop till the last record.

Comment: I am sorry,these approach is not best practice

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,scanSpec should be as follows:

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
                  .withFilterExpression("#category.#uid = :categoryuid").withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#category","skills").with("#uid",queryString)) 
                     .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":categoryuid", queryString));
```